# Documentation of naming convention for Eclipse releases

Tags: eclipse

Is there a page in the eclipse documentation somewhere that explains the naming convention of the download packages.  For example, is  eclipse-jee-2021-03-R-win32-x86_64.zip 32 bit or 64 bit (the 32 and the 64 in the name suggests it could be either), what does the "R" signify, etc.

Also, I'm having a hard time finding documentation showing what releases support which version of Java (e.g. Java 8 v Java 11).

Comment: The current release of Eclipse supports all versions of Java. The version of Java that Eclipse needs to run has nothing to do with the versions of Java you can program in.

Comment: Where did you look for the information and why does it matter to you? `win32` means the operation system is Windows, `x86_64` means an x86 64 bit architecture, `R` means release (e.g. not a build, milestone or release candidate). As greg-449 already said, Eclipse has its own compiler that support a wide range of Java version, Java 8 and Java 11 included for years.

Comment: I think it is 'win32' just for historical reasons. Recent releases of Eclipse are 64 bit only.

Comment: The Java 8 v Java 11 version becomes important when integrating plugins.  For example, JBoss plugins will give "Java 11 required" errors for some builds of Eclipse (I could not get my Java 8 version of JBoss to run on later versions of Eclipse and migrated everything to Java 11 compatible versions).

Comment: What kind of plugins do you mean? Plugins you want to install into Eclipse? `eclipse-jee-2021-03-R-win32-x86_64.zip` is one release behind and contains a Java 16 JDK to run Eclipse. Independent from that, you have to configure the Java JDKs/JREs to be used in your project and launch configurations in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_.

Comment: The plugins I'm talking about here are the JBoss plugins used to connect to a Wildfly 24 server (i.e. what gets installed when you click on the "Create new server link" and select the Wildfly 24 option.

Comment: The current JBoss plugins runs in the current Eclipse with the Java contained in `eclipse-jee-2021-06-R-win32-x86_64.zip`. Even though this is a Java 16 VM, you can still code and run your code with any Java version up to Java 16, including Java 8 and 11, that is configured in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_. For details read the documentation (_Help > Help Contents_).

Answer (score 2):

eclipse-jee-2021-03-R-win32-x86_64.zip is:

| filename segment | what does it mean |
| --- | --- |
| eclipse-jee | package name, usually heavily shortened |
| 2021-03 | simultaneous release, based on the release month |
| R | Is this the final release (R), a milestone along the way (M), or a release candidate (RC) |
| win32 | window system, the native UI API that it uses |
| x86_64 | supported CPU architecture |

Comment: Thanks @nitnd, is this in the eclipse documentation somewhere?  There seem to be some other indicators, for example there is a package that includes "incubation" in the name (eclipse-jee-2020-03-R-incubation-win32-x86_64.zip).  What does "incubation" mean? https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2020-03/R/eclipse-jee-2020-03-R-incubation-win32-x86_64.zip

Comment: I'm not sure, it just might have been treated as an implementation detail of the EPP build since the downloads and installer don't expose the full filenames.

Incubation refers to one of the stages in the [Eclipse Development Process'](https://www.eclipse.org/projects/dev_process/#6_2_Project_Lifecycle) lifecycles, and that label indicates they contain the output of projects that are in Incubation. Sometimes the importance if it is disregarded too easily, IMHO. I want projects to exit incubation as soon as they can to show that they're planning to stick around and be supported.

Comment: ...and Incubation has no direct relation to whether a project's output is stable enough for use.