# Eclipse workspace corrupted after saving as zip

Tags: eclipse

I have a need to share an eclipse workspace as a zip file.  However, when I zip the workspace and then unzip it all of the user configuration is lost including the project that was opened in the workspace, what views are showing, and even a JBoss server that was created.

If I copy and paste the workspace everything works fine.

If I zip and unzip all of the configuration is lost (i.e. when I launch Eclipse and use the unzipped workspace Eclipse opens with all of the default settings including the welcome page).

What could be causing this and how do I get the zip to work?

I know there are other ways to export Eclipse configurations but I do have a specific requirement that this be provided as a zip file.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like this might be the problem here: https://blog.robertelder.org/zipping-corrupts-eclipse-workspace/

Comment: It does not work that way. That's why there are export and import functions. The blog post mentioned seems to be unrelated to me. You still have an [open question, with comments you haven't responded to yet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69074477/6505250).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was with the file names that started with ".".  I re-zipped with WinZip instead of the built-in windows tool and everything is working now.  See: blog.robertelder.org/zipping-corrupts-eclipse-workspace